# Know if specific column is identity (in SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, identity, identity-column

I am iterating through a list of database columns using this code:

```
adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" & i & "'", connection)
Dim ds_cols As New DataSet
adapter.Fill(ds_cols)

For Each c As DataRow In ds_cols.Tables(0).Rows
 'doing lots of things in here


Next
```

Now, i would need to query the database (or even better edit the existing one) to know if the current column i am analizing is an identity column.

Thank you

Comment: Use `sys.columns` instead of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`. That contains details about proprietary features such as `IDENTITY`. Also use parameterised queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the `sys.columns` view:

```
SELECT
    name, is_identity 
FROM sys.columns
WHERE name = 'YourColumnName' AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.YourTableName')
```

If you need the type of the column, you need to join to `sys.types`:

```
SELECT
    ColumnName = c.name ,
    c.is_identity,
    TypeName = ty.name
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.types ty ON ty.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
WHERE name = 'YourColumnName' AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.YourTableName')
```

Comment: system_type_id returns integers (56 instead of INT, 167 instead of varchar, and so on) can this be converted somehow?

Comment: @sharkyenergy: look into the `sys.types` view

Comment: for some reason, on some tables it is returning some columns twice.. with different user_type_id's.. do you happen to know why?

Answer (score 0):

Using below query will give you 2 columns i.e name of column and whether it is identity or not.I guess thats what you need

```
SELECT name, is_identity FROM sys.columns
WHERE   object_id = OBJECT_ID('tableName')
```